# how to give grant to a jar file to execute an another jar file

Tags: java, jar, policy, sql-grant

I want to execute a jar file with using policy file from my project. my policy file is:

```
*grant codeBase "file:///D:/xx/yy/zz/-"{
  permission java.io.FilePermission 
    "D:/aa/bb/test.jar", "read, write, delete, execute";
};*
```

my project is under D:/xx/yy/zz/ folder and i want to execute test.jar in this project but i had an error:

access denied (java.io.FilePermission <> execute)

if i change policy file like this, that is ok:

```
*grant codeBase "file:///D:/xx/yy/zz/-"{
  permission java.io.FilePermission 
    "<<ALL FILES>>", "read, write, delete, execute";
};*
```

But i do not want to give all permission to my project.

And also in project i set policy file like this:

String path="D:\aa\bb\test.jar";

```
     System.setProperty("java.security.policy","C:\\policy\\"+"test.policy");

     System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
```

Is there any body to say something about this situation ? 
Thanks...

Comment: Are you using a Windows filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this `"D:/aa/bb/test.jar"` should be `"D:\\aa\\bb\\test.jar"`

Check here for more info http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

It'looks a way more like a file system security problem than a java security exception, are you using windows or linux?
What kind of file system are you using ? ext2/3/4 or NFTS or fat32 ?
And most important, are you running your program with admin right, which might be necessary to grant execute permission on some files.

Comment: my questions changed a little bit: i realize that it is about java command. my code is:                                                       ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);          process = pb.start();                                            cmdList is like "java", "-jar", path                                  In start function, there is an security manager control with checkexec(). The exception is thrown from there.